# Save props to state to force update?

Tags: reactjs

Do I need to store my props to state so that the component will update when the props change?  Or can I just use `accounts` and it will update the component when the prop changes?

Here's my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {
        user: {accounts}
    } = props;
    this.state = {
        accounts
    };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevProps) {
    if (prevProps !== nextProps) {
        const {
            user: {accounts}
        } = nextProps;
        this.setState({
            accounts
        });
    }
}

render() {
    const {
        accounts
    } = this.state;
    return (...);
}
```

Comment: If your props come from a higher component that mutates props then the component won't re render. It depends on how you change the props your component receives but changing props (not mutating) should re render the component.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is depreciated and it is not needed here, your state as well, remove them. Use `this.props.user.accounts` directly. Each time your props change your component will be rerendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or can I just use accounts and it will update the component when the prop changes?

Yes, you just use `this.props.accounts` and it will update your child component.

What you need to do is remove the rest and just get `accounts` from props

```
render() {
    const {
        accounts
    } = this.props;
    return (...);
}
```

Then, when the props change, your component will update. No need to store it in the state.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want with the `account` field. If `account` just using in one component you can store it in state. If `account` using in 2 component or more. You need to store it in props. So you can share it another child.

Example: Assume you have A component. B and C are children of A.

- If B and C want to use this `account`. Store `account` in the prop of A.
- If only B using `account` store it in state of B.